# Не изменяется состояние в компоненте, но изменяется в store, mobx. Приложение обвернуто в strict mode

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Есть стор с категорией, которая просто изменяется селектом. Состояние в сторе изменяется, но не прилетает в компонент.
store:

```
import {makeAutoObservable} from 'mobx' 
class Categories{
    category: string='all'
    constructor(){
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }
    changeCategory(newCategory:string){
        this.category=newCategory
    }
}
export default new Categories()
```

component:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { Box, Typography,Select,MenuItem, SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material'
import categories from './../../store/categories'
import {observer} from 'mobx-react-lite'
const Categories = observer(() => {
  useEffect(()=>console.log(categories.category),[])
  return (
    <Box sx={{width:456 ,display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', gap: '10px'}}>
        <Typography color="#fff" fontWeight='600' variant='h6'>Categories</Typography>
        <Select
          value={categories.category} displayEmpty size='small'
          style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', width:'300px', boxShadow: '-1px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2)'}}
          onChange={(event:SelectChangeEvent)=>categories.changeCategory(event.target.value)}
        >
            <MenuItem value={'all'}>all</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'art'}>art</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'biography'}>biography</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'computers'}>computers</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'history'}>history</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'medical'}>medical</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'poetry'}>poetry</MenuItem>
        </Select>
    </Box>
  )
})

export default Categories
```

Comment: `useEffect(()=>console.log(categories.category),[])` такой `useEffect` не будет показывать какие-то изменения в состоянии, т.к. список его зависимостей пуст. Он выполнится только в момент создания компонета.

Comment: "Есть стор с категорией, которая просто изменяется селектом"... Так же, `Select` не есть `select` - что там и как "меняется" мы тут не видим...